# Problem storing a hash in DB using Storable::nfreeze in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, storable, freeze-thaw

I want to insert a hash in the db using Storable::nfreeze but the data is not inserted properly.

My code is as follows:

```
%rec=();
$rec{'name'} = 'my name';
$rec{'address'} = 'my address';

my $order1 = new Order();
$order1->set_session(\%rec);
$self->createOrder($order1);

sub createOrder {
my $self  = $_[0];
my $order = $_[1];


# Retrieve the fields to insert into the database.
my $st = $dbh->prepare("insert into order (session,.......) values(?,........)");

my $session   = %{$order->get_session()};
$st->execute(&Storable::nfreeze(\%session),.....);
$st->finish();

}

sub getOrder
{
     ...

    my $session = &Storable::thaw( $ref->{'session'} );
    .....
}
```

The `thaw` is working fine because I tested it withe some rows that have been inserted correctly, but when I try to get a row that was inserted using the `createOrder` subroutine, I get an error saying:

> Storable binary image v36.65 more recent than I am (v2.7) at blib/lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into blib/lib/auto/Storable/thaw.al) line 415

The error comes from the line that have `thaw`. The `nfreeze` did not store the hash properly.

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong in the `createOrder` subroutine?

I know the module version have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Sam => You have a number of open questions without accepted answers.  Assuming there is a good answer, click the check mark next to that answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably improper dereferencing here:

```
my $session   = %{$order->get_session()};
$st->execute(&Storable::nfreeze(\%session),.....);
```

This should fix it:

```
my $session   = $order->get_session();
$st->execute(&Storable::nfreeze($session),.....);
```

Since `->get_session`returns a hash reference, when you dereferenced it in scalar context it was turning into a string that contains statistics on the hash.  The hash `%session` is the empty package variable `%main::session` which you would have caught if you were running with `use strict; use warnings;`.